# Make cat command to operate recursively looping through a directory

Tags: bash, shell, cat, data-manipulation

I have a large directory of data files which I am in the process of manipulating to get them in a desired format. They each begin and end 15 lines too soon, meaning I need to strip the first 15 lines off one file and paste them to the end of the *previous* file in the sequence.

To begin, I have written the following code to separate the relevant data into easy chunks:

```
#!/bin/bash

destination='media/user/directory/'
for file1 in `ls $destination*.ascii`
do
    echo $file1
    file2="${file1}.end"
    file3="${file1}.snip"
    sed -e '16,$d' $file1 > $file2
    sed -e '1,15d' $file1 > $file3
done
```

This worked perfectly, so the next step is the worlds simplest `cat` command:

```
cat $file3 $file2 > outfile
```

**However**, what I need to do is to stitch `file2` to the **previous** `file3`. [Look at this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5NZq.png) of the directory for better understanding.

See how these files are all sequential over time:

```
*_20090412T235945_20090413T235944_*    ### April 13
*_20090413T235945_20090414T235944_*    ### April 14
```

So I need to take the 15 lines snipped off the April 14 example above and paste it to the end of the April 13 example.

This doesn't have to be part of the original code, in fact it would be probably best if it weren't. I was just hoping someone would be able to help me get this going.

Thanks in advance! If there is anything I have been unclear about and needs further explanation please let me know.

Comment: Can't you just use `>> $file3` to append to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I need to strip the first 15 lines off one file and paste them to the end of the previous file in the sequence."

If I understand what you want correctly, it can be done with one line of code:

```
awk 'NR==1 || FNR==16{close(f); f=FILENAME ".new"} {print>f}' file1 file2 file3
```

When this has run, the files `file1.new`, `file2.new`, and `file3.new` will be in the new form with the lines transferred.  Of course, you are not limited to three files: you may specify as many as you like on the command line.

#### Example

To keep our example short, let's just strip the first 2 lines instead of 15.  Consider these test files:

```
$ cat file1
1
2
3
$ cat file2
4
5
6
7
8
$ cat file3
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Here is the result of running our command:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || FNR==3{close(f); f=FILENAME ".new"} {print>f}' file1 file2 file3
$ cat file1.new
1
2
3
4
5
$ cat file2.new
6
7
8
9
10
$ cat file3.new
11
12
13
14
15
```

As you can see, the first two lines of each file have been transferred to the preceding file.

#### How it works

awk implicitly reads each file line-by-line.  The job of our code is to choose which new file a line should be written to based on its line number.  The variable `f` will contain the name of the file that we are writing to.

- `NR==1 || FNR==16{f=FILENAME ".new"}`

  When we are reading the first line of the first file, `NR==1`, or when we are reading the 16th line of whatever file we are on, `FNR==16`, we update `f` to be the name of the current file with `.new` added to the end.

  For the short example, which transferred 2 lines instead of 15, we used the same code but with `FNR==16` replaced with `FNR==3`.
- `print>f`

  This prints the current line to file `f`.

  (If this was a shell script, we would use `>>`.  This is not a shell script. This is awk.)

#### Using a glob to specify the file names

```
destination='media/user/directory/'
awk 'NR==1 || FNR==16{close(f); f=FILENAME ".new"} {print>f}'  "$destination"*.ascii
```

Comment: Thank you for what looks like a very simple fix. Just one question, if I wanted to call all of my files into this line how would I go about doing it as opposed to how you did with `file1 file2 file3` (since there are ~1500 files)? Would I use the same `for file1 in ls` command that I used for my initial script? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Vlad I just added to the end of the answer code to replace the `for file in...`.

Comment: It appeared to be working but malfunctioned about 2/3 of the way through the directory with the awk error `too many open files`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Vlad Sorry about that!  Yes, I should have explicitly closed the files.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the previous `$file3` value in a variable (and do a check if it is not the first run with `-z` check):

```
#!/bin/bash

destination='media/user/directory/'
prev=""
for file1 in $destination*.ascii
do
    echo $file1
    file2="${file1}.end"
    file3="${file1}.snip"
    sed -e '16,$d' $file1 > $file2
    sed -e '1,15d' $file1 > $file3
    if [ -z "$prev" ]; then
       cat $prev $file2 > outfile
    fi
    prev=$file3
done
```

Comment: Hesitantly abstaining from downvoting, but you should really fix the [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls) and the broken quoting from the OP's attempt.

Comment: Thank you for the time to answer me. I tried this code and defined my outfile as `file4=${file1}.done"` as I had done elsewhere in the code. It ran without error, however only gave me one iteration of a `.done` file at the beginning and didn't continue through the rest of the directory.

Comment: @tripleee I tried to make minimal changes to make it work so other changes don't cover what was the real point. What do you mean by *broken quoting*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

Your task is not that difficult at all. You want to gather a list of all `_end` files in the directory (using a `for` loop and globbing, NOT looping on the results of `ls`). Once you have all the `end` files, you simply parse the dates using *parameter expansion w/substing removal* say into `d1` and `d2` for date1 and date2 in:

```
stuff_20090413T235945_20090414T235944_end
     |    d1  |      |    d2  |
```

then you simply subtract `1` from `d1` into say date0 or `d0` and then construct a previous filename out of `d0` and `d1` using `_snip` instead of `_end`. Then just test for the existence of the previous `_snip` filename, and if it exists, paste your info from the current `_end` file to the previous `_snip` file. e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *end; do         ## find all _end files
    d1="${i#*stuff_}"     ## isolate first date in filename
    d1="${d1%%T*}"
    d2="${i%T*}"          ## isolate second date
    d2="${d2##*_}"
    d0=$((d1 - 1))        ## subtract 1 from first, get snip d1
    prev="${i/$d1/$d0}"   ## create previous 'snip' filename
    prev="${prev/$d2/$d1}"
    prev="${prev%end}snip"
    if [ -f "$prev" ]     ## test that prev snip file exists
    then
        printf "paste to : %s\n" "$prev"
        printf "    from : %s\n\n" "$i"
    fi
done
```

**Test Input Files**

```
$ ls -1
stuff_20090413T235945_20090414T235944_end
stuff_20090413T235945_20090414T235944_snip
stuff_20090414T235945_20090415T235944_end
stuff_20090414T235945_20090415T235944_snip
stuff_20090415T235945_20090416T235944_end
stuff_20090415T235945_20090416T235944_snip
stuff_20090416T235945_20090417T235944_end
stuff_20090416T235945_20090417T235944_snip
stuff_20090417T235945_20090418T235944_end
stuff_20090417T235945_20090418T235944_snip
stuff_20090418T235945_20090419T235944_end
stuff_20090418T235945_20090419T235944_snip
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash endsnip.sh
paste to : stuff_20090413T235945_20090414T235944_snip
    from : stuff_20090414T235945_20090415T235944_end

paste to : stuff_20090414T235945_20090415T235944_snip
    from : stuff_20090415T235945_20090416T235944_end

paste to : stuff_20090415T235945_20090416T235944_snip
    from : stuff_20090416T235945_20090417T235944_end

paste to : stuff_20090416T235945_20090417T235944_snip
    from : stuff_20090417T235945_20090418T235944_end

paste to : stuff_20090417T235945_20090418T235944_snip
    from : stuff_20090418T235945_20090419T235944_end
```

(of course replace `stuff_` with your actual prefix)

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will certainly put this to the test and report back. Just one question, where in this do I define the outfiles for each of the newly pasted files?

Comment: What my understanding of what you want to do is, for each `_end` file, you will take the lines you need to paste to the previous `_snip` file. Since you have the `_end` file, do that in whatever manner you currently are. Then using the dates from the `_end` file name, you locate the appropriate `_snip` file to add that information to (that is the `$prev` file. If you simply need to add the lines to the end of the `_snip` file, just redirect the line (e.g. `echo "$lines_from_end" >> "$prev"`